# How to keep jvm in sync with database, whether an update was successful or not, even if JVM crashes after updation was successful

Tags: java, database, transactions

Given the following scenario:

1. Java statement to update a database table.
2. Update successful in database.
3. Before database could signal the java process that the update was successful, the JVM crashes.

How to get this information from database - whether the update was successful or not -  after restarting the JVM?

Comment: Can anyone answer this pls?